Sequentially Numbering Footnotes with React
I'm trying to create a footnote component for my new React version of my blog, but, so far, I'm not able to get the numbering right.
I'm applying basically the same logic I did for my Web Components version of the same blog component:

Calculate the current footnote index based on how many footnotes you can document.querySelectorAll(".footnote").
Use that index for the <sup> tag where the footnote should appear.
Append the footnote index and content to a footnotes container at the end of the post.

I think this won't work due to the rendering sequence React uses. Is there a workaround? Maybe there's a query selector method for taking only elements before a certain element?
Here's an example of what I have so far:


function Article() {
  return (
    <article>
      <p>The<FootNote html="Footnote 1" /> article content here<FootNote html="Footnote 2" />.</p>
      <FootNotesContainer />
    </article>
  )
}

function FootNotesContainer() {
  return (
    <div id="footnotes-container">
      <h2>Footnotes</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

function FootNote({ html }) {
  const [footNoteLink, setFootNoteLink] = React.useState("")
   
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const previousFootnotes =
      document.querySelectorAll(".footnote")
    const nextFootNoteNumber = previousFootnotes.length
         setFootNoteLink(nextFootNoteNumber.toString())

    const footNoteContent = document.createElement("div")
    footNoteContent.innerHTML = /* html */ `
      <a 
        href="#footnote-base-${nextFootNoteNumber}"
        id="footnote-${nextFootNoteNumber}"
        className="no-underline"
      >${nextFootNoteNumber}</a>:
      ${html}
    `

    const footNoteContainer = document.querySelector(
      "#footnotes-container"
    )
    footNoteContainer.appendChild(footNoteContent)
  }, [html])


  return (
    <sup className="footnote">
      <a
        href={`#footnote-${footNoteLink}`}
        id={`footnote-base-${footNoteLink}`}
        className="text-orange-400 no-underline"
      >
        {footNoteLink}
      </a>
    </sup>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(
  <Article />
)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



I've also tried doing it in a more Reactish way, but I don't know why the list being provided by the context isn't being copied/mutated sequentially:


const FootnotesContext = React.createContext(null)

function FootnotesProvider({ children }) {
  const [footnotes, setFootnotes] = React.useState([])
  
  function addFootnote(html) {
    setFootnotes([...footnotes, html])
  }
  
  function totalFootnotes() {
    return footnotes.length
  }

  return (
    <FootnotesContext.Provider value={{ footnotes, addFootnote, totalFootnotes }}>
      {children}
    </FootnotesContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useFootnotes() {
  const context = React.useContext(FootnotesContext)
  
  if (!context) throw new Error("`useFootnotes` must be used within a `FootnotesProvider`.")
  
  return context
}

function Article() {
  return (
    <FootnotesProvider>
      <article>
        <p>The
          <FootNote html="Footnote 1" />{" "}
          article content here
          <FootNote html="Footnote 2" />.
        </p>

        <hr/>

        <FootNotesContainer />
      </article>
    </FootnotesProvider>
  )
}

function FootNotesContainer() {
  const { footnotes } = useFootnotes()
  
  console.log(footnotes)
  
  return (
    <div id="footnotes-container">
      <h2>Footnotes</h2>
      <h3>Total Footnotes: {footnotes.length}</h3>
      
      {
        footnotes.map((f, i) => (
          <div className="footnote" key={i}>
            <a 
              href={`#footnote-sup-${i}`}
              id={`footnote-${i}`}
            >{i + 1}</a>:
            <p>{f}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

function FootNote({ html }) {
  const { footnotes, addFootnote, totalFootnotes } = useFootnotes()
  
  const i = totalFootnotes() + 1

  React.useEffect(() => {
    addFootnote(html)
  }, [])

  return (
    <sup className="footnote-sup">
      <a
        href={`#footnote-${i}`}
        id={`footnote-sup-${i}`}
      >
        {i}
      </a>
    </sup>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Article />)
.footnote {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




Don't use this incrementing anti-pattern at all. IDs should be both unique and permanent because they become part of the URL. If the order of some of the content in the page markup changes, then using a generated integer sequence will break existing links to footnotes — e.g. a link that previously pointed to the content for "footnote 2" might point to content for "footnote 5".

Yes, ideally, I should make IDs non-sequential. But that's also a matter of me editing things in the end, after all, I could also edit the headings, which might also break links. I get that in this way, it's another scale of a problem because editing one footnote will edit many others. At any rate, the footnote IDs and the footnote numbering don't need to both have the algorithm behind them.

Based on your comment to an answer below it certainly appears you understand the "React way" is to have some centralized source of truth, e.g. state, that is provided, e.g. React Context API, to the descendent FootNote components. There's not much to implementing this so it's not clear what "simpler" solution you are looking for. Querying and mutating the DOM is definitely not a React way of going about this.

My comment was about his hack for a shared counter, not about what I did for the mutating the DOM part, which I do not think is Reactish in any way, shape, or form. And, by the way, I used the term "more React way", not "React way", not to mention that I didn't make any overarching assumptions about that user (and I did upvote his answer because I thought it was helpful).

Sorry, I can see where the ambiguity lies. Mine was really two separate comments. (1) referencing your comment that you know you should us a "more React way" by using a React Context, and (2) referencing your current implementation querying and mutating the DOM in your [mcve], which is a clear and established React anti-pattern.

I've just added a version that uses a React provider, but I don't know why the list isn't being mutated properly, or how to fix it.

Where is the data for your blog coming from? If it's JSON couldn't you have the footnotes in a separate array and then just simply map over them? @psygo

In my blog, my articles are just HTML files. I import the <foot-note> Web Component at the top. It was meant to be a simple static, content website.

with context, without state
Here's my first attempt at it. I chose React useRef because we should be able to accomplish the goal with a single render. Whenever the provider renders, it resets its local ref. As the provider's children render, ref is updated.
function App() {
  return <div>
    <p>
      Hello <Footnote children="hello" />.
      <Child />
      World <Footnote children="world" />.
    </p>
    <Footnotes />
  </div>
}

function Child() {
  return <span>More text from the child
    <Footnote children="more" />
    and a little more <Footnote children="and more"/>.
  </span>
}

As you can see this works for Footnote components that appear at different levels in the component tree. One caveat to this approach is the footnotes list must be rendered after all individual Footnote components -
Hello [1].More text from the child[2]and a little more [3].World [4].

[1]: hello
[2]: more
[3]: and more
[4]: world
We can implement Footnote and Footnotes as -
function Footnote(props) {
  const context = React.useContext(Context)
  const id = context.add(props.children)
  return <sup>[{id}]</sup>
}

function Footnotes() {
  const context = React.useContext(Context)
  return <ul>
    {context.get().map((children, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        [{index + 1}]: {children}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
}

And the Context and Provider -
const defaultContext = {
  get: () => [],
  add: () => {
    throw Error(`add called outside of context`)
  }
}

const Context = React.createContext(defaultContext)

function Provider(props) {
  const footnotes = React.useRef([])
  footnotes.current = []
  const add = children => footnotes.current.push(children)
  const get = () => footnotes.current
  return <Context.Provider
    children={props.children}
    value={{ add, get }}
  />
}

Run the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -


const defaultContext = {
  get: () => [],
  add: () => {
    throw Error(`add called outside of context`)
  }
}

const Context = React.createContext(defaultContext)

function Provider(props) {
  const footnotes = React.useRef([])
  footnotes.current = []
  const add = children => footnotes.current.push(children)
  const get = () => footnotes.current
  return <Context.Provider
    children={props.children}
    value={{ add, get }}
  />
}

function Footnote(props) {
  const context = React.useContext(Context)
  const id = context.add(props.children)
  return <sup>[{id}]</sup>
}

function Footnotes() {
  const context = React.useContext(Context)
  return <ul>
    {context.get().map((children, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        [{index + 1}]: {children}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
}

function App() {
  return <div>
    <p>
      Hello <Footnote children="hello" />.
      <Child />
      World <Footnote children="world" />.
    </p>
    <Footnotes />
  </div>
}

function Child() {
  return <span>More text from the child
    <Footnote children="more" />
    and a little more <Footnote children="and more"/>.
  </span>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>



I'll leave it to you to create actual a elements and generate the corresponding href. To ensure URLs stay the same, I would advise not using the footnote's number as part of the URL.
An improvement may be to return a component from the context's add function so the Footnote component does not take on this concern -
function Provider(props) {
  const add = children => {
    const id = footnotes.current.push(children)
    const fragment = children.split(" ").join("-")
    return <a href=`#${encodeURIComponent(fragment)}`>${id}</a>
  return // ...
}

function Footnote(props) {
  const context = React.useContext(Context)
  const link = context.add(props.children) // <a href=...>...</a>
  return <sup>[{link}]</sup>
}

If you find drawbacks to this approach, please share and I'll try to address them ^-^


I don't know why @NephiBalinski deleted his answer, but here it is just for reference, since I thought it was useful. It basically uses a mix of my second snippet and what @Mulan ended up coming up with.


1. The React Context way
One way to solve this is using React Context. Here is the revised and updated code using React Context:


const FootnotesContext = React.createContext(null);

function FootnotesProvider({ children }) {
  const [footnotes, setFootnotes] = React.useState([]);
  const footnotesRef = React.useRef([]);

  function addFootnote(html) {
    footnotesRef.current = [...footnotesRef.current, html];
    setFootnotes([...footnotesRef.current, ]);
  }

  function totalFootnotes() {
    return footnotes.length;
  }

  return (
    <FootnotesContext.Provider value={{ footnotes, addFootnote, totalFootnotes,  }}>
      {children}
    </FootnotesContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useFootnotes() {
  const context = React.useContext(FootnotesContext);

  if (!context) throw new Error('`useFootnotes` must be used within a `FootnotesProvider`.');

  return context;
}

function Article() {
  return (
    <FootnotesProvider>
      <article>
        <p>
          The <FootNote html="Footnote 1" /> article content here <FootNote html="Footnote 2" />.
        </p>

        <hr />

        <FootNotesContainer />
      </article>
    </FootnotesProvider>
  );
}

function FootNotesContainer() {
  const { footnotes } = useFootnotes();

  return (
    <div id="footnotes-container">
      <h2>Footnotes</h2>
      <h3>Total Footnotes: {footnotes.length}</h3>

      {footnotes.map((f, i) => (
        <div className="footnote" key={i}>
          <a href={`#footnote-sup-${i + 1}`} id={`footnote-${i}`}>
            {i + 1}
          </a>:
          <p>{f}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function FootNote({ html }) {
  const { footnotes, addFootnote, totalFootnotes } = useFootnotes();
  // const footnoteRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    addFootnote(html);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIndex(footnotes.indexOf(html) + 1)
  }, [footnotes])

  return (
    <sup 
      className="footnote-sup" 
      // ref={ref => footnoteRef.current = ref}
    >
      <a
        href={`#footnote-${index}`}
        id={`footnote-sup-${index}`}
      >
        {index}
      </a>
    </sup>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Article />);
.footnote {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Key changes

We added a footnotesRef to ensures that footnotes are added sequentially.
We restructured the FootNote component to correct render footnote numbering.
We corrected the links in FootNotesContainer.
We didn't use DOM manipulation!

This should fix the footnotes issue.
2. The generator way (not recommended)
Another approach is using ES6 generator functions. Here is an example of a basic generator function:
function* genId() {
    var index = 0;
    while (true)
        yield index++;
    }
}

let gen = genId();

console.log(gen.next().value); // 0
console.log(gen.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen.next().value); // 2

Here is the revised and updated code:


function Article() {
  return (
    <article>
      <p>The<FootNote html="Footnote 1" /> article content here<FootNote html="Footnote 2" />.</p>
      <FootNotesContainer />
    </article>
  );
}

function FootNotesContainer() {
  return (
    <div id='footnotes-container'>
      <h2>Footnotes</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function* generateId() {
  let idCounter = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield idCounter++;
  }
}

const gen = generateId();

function useFootnoteId() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setId(gen.next().value);
  }, [gen]);

  return id;
}

function FootNote({ html }) {
  const footNoteLink = useFootnoteId();
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.14.1/runtime.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Key changes

We no longer use previousFootnotes.length to calculate what footNoteLink is. Instead we use useFootnoteId and generateId functions.

Note: We've removed DOM reads, so actions like deleting footnotes may require extra steps.


We implemented a cleanup function in FootNotesContainer to avoid unnecessary footnote creation due to excessive re-renders.

Now footnotes should work the way you want them to.
